# Can I use both the arcana Empowered Magic (Su) and the Empower Spell (Metamagic) on one spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, metamagic, magus

My magus has Magical Lineage (Shocking Grasp) and Intensified Spell. My magus can cast a Shocking Grasp with a 1 level spell slot up to 10CL.

At level 6, I chose the magus arcana [Empowered Magic (Su)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/empowered-magic-su/):

> The magus can cast one spell per day as if it were modified by the Empower Spell feat. This does not increase the casting time or the level of the spell.

I can Shocking grasp at 6d6+3d6 once a day in a 1 level spell slot

At Level 7, I picked the feat [Empower Spell (Metamagic)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic-final).

I can Shocking Grasp at 7d6+3d6 in a 3 level spell slot.

Also, can I use both together? If so, will it be 7d6+3d6+3d6 (7d6+7d6*0.5+7d6*0.5) or 7d6+3d6+5d6 ((7d6+7d6*0.5)*0.5) in a 3 level spell slot once a day?

I know about the [multiple metamagic feats on a spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/):

> Multiple Metamagic Feats on a Spell: A spellcaster can apply multiple metamagic feats to a single spell. Changes to its level are cumulative. **You can’t apply the same metamagic feat more than once to a single spell.**

In my case, I am not sure this rule will disallow to use both together or not. The arcana is not the feat, but the arcana apply the same effect. Note that the metamagic feat apply at preparation time and the arcana at casting time (but I am not sure that it will matter).

**Can I use both the arcana Empowered Magic (Su) and the Empower Spell (Metamagic) on one spell?**

Comment: As a side note, Shocking Grasp has a maximum 5d6 damage before metamagic is applied.

Comment: @McCurran true. But all my Shocking Grasp are under Intensified Spell (+0 with magical lineage).

Comment: @A.McCurran (I, too, initially missed the *and Intensified Spell* in the first sentence. Please consider, aloisdg, linking to game mechanics that have an effect on the question… if only to call attention to them because they'll be turned red!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording says "As if it were modified by the Empower Spell Feat"

You could activate the ability, but the effects wouldn't stack. If you apply this ability to a normal spell, it adds the effect of the Empower Spell Feat. If you apply this ability to a spell that has been prepared with Empower Spell, then it does nothing, since it already is modified by the Empower Spell Feat.

An Empowered Spell is always treated "as if it is modified by the Empower Spell Feat"